# How can I limit requests to AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-s3

I have a free account on AWS S3 that provides 5 free GB per month for storing media files. How can I not get out from this free limit? Can I block storage requests when the limit is exceeded?

Answer (score 0):

As an option you can generate S3 consumption events via CloudWatch/CloudTrail and have Lambda waiting for an event of a specific consumption reached.
You can disable write access to buckets in the handler of this event from this Lambda.